# Can't access the WEB API Cookie via document.cookie in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, asp.net-web-api2, form-authentication

I Implemented a AngularJS Project, Service Side implementation I used the .NET WEB API. For Authorization I'm using

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(token, false);
```

It's coming fine in browser Cookies.

[image]

[image]

But I can't able to get the cookies in JavaScript

[image]

Kindly assist me, why It's coming empty ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that `.MDAUTH` cookie is set as `HttpOnly`. This means only the server side will be able to access the cookie and not the client side. You need to explicitly set `HttpOnly` to `false` while setting the cookie in the backend.